# pipe record to object param list

Tags: f#

Given i have the type:

```
type NewsMessage(identifier:string, headline:string)
```

and this record:

```
type NewsMessageParams = { 
    identifier:string
    headline:string 
}
```

Is there an implicit way to adapt the record into the class constructor?

Something like so:

```
let newsMessageParmas = {identifier=""; headline=""}
new NewsMessage(newsMessageParams) //this is where i need help
```

You can do this with tuples using the `||>` syntax. I would like to do this with a record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
let toClass {identifier = i; headline = h} = NewsMessage(i, h)

// Usage
let newsMessageParams = {identifier = ""; headline = ""}
let newsMessage = newsMessageParams |> toClass
```

Note that object constructor isn't first-class in F#, so you have more chances of using pipe operators if declaring `NewsMessage` as discriminated unions:

```
type NewsMessage = NewsMessage of string * string
let toTuple {identifier = i; headline = h} = i, h

let newsMessageParams = {identifier = ""; headline = ""}
let newsMessage = newsMessageParams |> toTuple |> NewsMessage
```